# Is new/faster RAM worth it compared to older memroy witht he same size?

Tags: memory

I am currently building a new PC i5, rx480, SSD and also need a new mainboard (obviously) i could use my old RAM 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 or i could buy a new set at around 100€ (16GB as well 2800-3200 MHz not sure yet).
Will there be a notable performance boost in gaming mainly a MMO called black desert.

Comment: The only program I've ever used that showed visible improvement with faster RAM is Dwarf Fortress, due to the way it stores its objects, and cycles through all of them with each framedraw. it will bring the most powerful workhorses to their knees. http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/

Comment: "Will there be a notable performance boost or is it better to keep the old one?" - You didn't tell us the frequency of the new memory.  If its the same frequency you will see zero difference.  If the frequency is less then double then you won't be able to measure much of a difference.  It all depends.

Answer (score 1):

Your question the way it is asked, is really a matter of opinion.  You should reword it to meet the sites requirements.

However, having said that, the answer is probably no.  Faster memory *is* faster.  However, *how much faster* is the key.  Generally speaking, you are looking at single digit percent speed gains.  Unless you are running very memory intense applications that are constantly reading and writing to memory, you wont see any difference.  Even if you are, you probably wont see the difference in the short term.  The general user isnt running in memory databases or large data manipulation where faster memory would show a difference in speed.